# rails model do something on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How can I go about writing a method in a model that should be called right before the model is destroyed?

For example I want to write a loop to update a bunch of stuff in another `Model B` when `Model A` is `destroyed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what callbacks are for, in your case you can use the before_destroy callback such as:

```
class ModelA
before_destroy :do_bunch_of_things

def do_bunch_of_things
...
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Active Record has three available callbacks called when an object is destroyed: `before_destroy`, `around_destroy` and `after_destroy`. An example:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :log_destroy_action

  def log_destroy_action
    puts 'Article destroyed'
  end
end
```

More information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html